# Magento /setup/ page is blank after installation (possible causes)?

Tags: magento2, installation, server-setup

When I'm tryin to install Magento 2 in the server it shows a blank page on installation(/setup/#/landing-install), like this image:

[image: Magento install with blank page]

Please suggest, what could be the issue?

Comment: Are you using nginx?

Comment: I have also faced same issue. So I have change the PHP version 7.3 and Magento 2.3 now it is works like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

I found out the problem was

```
the cgi.fix_pathinfo set to 0.
```

I have set it back to 1 as default and it now works fine.

> Just ';' Uncomment first, and add '= 1'

Answer (score 2):

Run these commands on the **root** of your Magento installation to give the permissions on the folders and to update your composer to prevent more issues.

```
composer install && composer update -vvvv &&
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

> Depending of your user, maybe you will need to use a **sudo** permit.

Comment: i got error if i install composer 

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Package fabpot/php-cs-fixer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer instead.
Generating autoload files

Comment: Try don't use the composer install only the update

Comment: it ask user name psw what i need to give

Comment: Use this tutorial to generate yours. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html

Comment: @RafaelCorrêaGomes : I have updated the composer and run command as mention above but did not work.

Comment: Copy the core files and paste, to stay right that any core files are original. So run the commands that I answered again.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned try making sure sure that your file permissions are set correctly:

File owner should always be Apache / www-data

Try setting the file permissions to 755 across the board for installation:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

**Potential Memory Issue**

I have had issues before where I try to go to the Magento 2 installer in the browser, and it just says **ERR:Empty Response** or shows a blank screen. I discovered this was that my server was struggling to provide enough memory to run the installer interface.

If this is the issue try installing Magento using the [command line](https://devblg.co.uk/how-to-install-magento-2/) installer:

```
php bin/magento setup:install 
--base-url="http://example.co.uk/" 
--db-host="localhost" 
--db-name="databasename" 
--db-user="databaseuser" 
--db-password="databasepass" 
--admin-firstname="Yourname" 
--admin-lastname="Yourname" 
--admin-email="hello@example.co.uk" 
--admin-user="admin" 
--admin-password="setpasswordhere" 
--language="en_GB" 
--currency="GBP" 
--timezone="Europe/London" 
--use-rewrites="1" 
--backend-frontname="admin"
```

I found this more suitable since I was having issues loading the installer interface but this didn't appear to require as much memory and finished quickly without any issues.

Comment: what is the file owner for Nginx?

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure you have given correct permissions to your magento files and directories?
[devdocs.magento.com](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html)

Answer (score 1):

- If you get blank screen when installing wizard then check your .htaccess file may be issue of it.check all extension are installed or not.

And if you get blank screen after installed wizard then please follow below step.

1. install magento with help of composer.
2. install it via install wizard
3. Give permission to folder,var,pub/media (Check permission)
4. Install sample data with  php bin/magento sampledata:deploy //install sample data
5. upgrade with php bin/magento setup:upgrade
6. compile with php bin/magento setup:di:compile

And then disable cache and set mode developer and clear static content

1. php bin/magento cache:disable
2. php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
3. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 1):

This may be issue with DOM, Please install php dom as per your php version.

For php 7.0.X use below command  :

sudo apt-get install php7.0-dom

don't forget to restart apache.

thanks